# Can comments appear before the DOCTYPE declaration?

Tags: html, comments, doctype

I would like to place a comment (`<!-- this -->` style) at the very top of my HTML code, preceding the DOCTYPE declaration. Does this conform to the standards? Is it supported by the major browsers? Are there any pitfalls in doing this?

Comment: The answers to this question are all outdated since they all mention Internet Explorer. I checked [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) and comments before doctype doesn't produce any warnings or errors, but other than that I haven't been able to find any proof of whether or not it's a good practice.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Writing the **`<!DOCTYPE>`** first is certainly best practice.

I remember strange problems a long, long time ago where some browser (probably IE6) ignored a **`<!DOCTYPE>`** because there was something seemingly innocent before it - I think just whitespace, but maybe it was a comment.  In any case, it was a horrible, horrible bug to have to track down, and there's certainly never any good reason to have comments or whitespace before the **`<!DOCTYPE>`**.

Writing the **`<!DOCTYPE>`** first is, I'd say, just something experienced web developers do to avoid horrible, elusive bugs.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to place my comment after the html tag instead.

Comment: It needs to come before everything including <html> if you want it to work correctly.

Comment: This just bit me. I spent 4 hours trying to figure out why IE7/8 rendered EVERYTHING OUT OF PLACE. After checking every single tag for proper closing braces and stuff, I created a new file and copied the code line by line (not the comments) and everything worked fine.

Completely baffled, I randomly thought "what if...?" when I noticed the comment line right before DOCTYPE in the original file. There was my culprit!

Comment: This issue is resolved in IE10. The comments before Doctype would not force IE10 to quirks mode.

Comment: With regards to using CKEditor, in case this helps someone, I also spend hours trying to work out why the CKEditor UI wasn't appearing IE7, IE8 or IE9, but worked ok in other browsers. Turns out it was simply a HTML comment appearing before the DOCTYPE line. Curse you, IE!

Comment: What about HTML comments at the very end of the HTML text? Could it produce errors?

Comment: @user1580348 No.

Answer (score 144):

It is **fully valid** to do

```
<!-- this, -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**However,** it brings **all** versions of IE into **quirks-mode** (unless it is *forced* into no-quirks mode — see the **Gotchas** section below). The simplest is to move the comment below the DOCTYPE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- this, -->
```

But another way is to *“upgrade”* the comment into a *suitable **conditional*** comment, such as this:

```
<!--[if !IE]> this <![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Explanation:** a *conditional* comment does not **count** as a comment, in IE's world.

**Alternative syntax:** To forget/remember that conditional comments are a Microsoft intrusion into the HTML standard, one could for instance do

```
<!--[if anybrowser]> this <![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Likewise, to target IE in particular, one could do

```
<!--[if !anybrowser]> this <![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Gotchas**

A comment *inside* a conditional comment will bring IE into quirks-mode **if IE sees it** (that is: **if** one uses an **[if IE]** condition, or an equivalent to [if IE] — such as the **[if !anybrowser]** condition that I mentioned above.). So, for example, this would bring IE in quirks-mode:

```
<![if IE]><!-- this --><![endif]>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

As would

```
<!--[if IE]><!--><!-- this <![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and many other variants. Whereas for example

```
<!--[if IE]><!DOCTYPE html><!--><!-- this <![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

would *not* cause quirks-mode, because *here* the conditional comment has a DOCTYPE *before **any other*** content, and thus IE considers that the first content of the page is a DOCTYPE.

Finally, the newest IE versions, *IE8 and IE9*, can be *forced* to standards-mode (and to quirks-mode as well) by the use of another Microsoft invention — the *x-ua-compatible* directive. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx In that case, then

```
<!-- this -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" ><![endif]-->
```

will **force** IE8 and IE9 into *no-quirks* mode, while IE6 and IE7 will remain in *quirks* mode. Whereas, in contrast, **this**

```
<!--[if gte IE 8]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" ><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

would **force** IE8 and IE9 into standards mode, **despite** that the content of the conditional comment does *not* start with a DOCTYPE. And IE6 and IE7 will also remain in no-quirks mode since the conditional comment doesn't target them.

Comment: I long ago decided to avoid the whole issue by placing my top comment after the DOCTYPE, but thanks for the detailed (and fascinating) explanation of IE's behavior.

Comment: A+ :) I'm going to take your word for it - this is an incredibly detailed response - thanks, I like it a lot. You clearly didn't stop in the face of the rabbithole :

Answer (score 13):

While it's acceptable per the standard I believe, you definately want to avoid it, as it'll throw IE into quirks mode.

(See [Triggering different rendering modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode))

Comment: Anything other than whitespace preceding the DOCTYPE throws IE (6 and 7, at least — not sure about 8) into quirks mode.

Answer (score 4):

That may cause IE7 to render in quirks mode as if a doctype was not there at all, according to [this page](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/forum/dijit-dijit-0-9/dijit-support/comment-doctype-declaration-causes-datetextbox-render-funny-ie).

Answer (score 1):

Comments before the doctype are allowed, but cause **all** IE versions to revert to quirks mode. They are, actually, used for that purpose sometimes. The XML declaration (`<?xml version ...?>`) have the same effect, *in IE6 and below*.