# Forcing intranet users to view webpage in IE8 mode, not compatibility mode

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-8, http-headers, ie8-compatibility-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

Although I'm specifying

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

But due to IE's "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting, my app isn't being viewed in IE8, but in compatibility mode.

Anyone know if there is a way round this???

Comment: V. Similar; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742853/force-internet-explorer-8-browser-mode-in-intranet/2755739#2755739

Comment: msdn forum question, no helpful answers : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/acf1e236-715b-4feb-8132-f88e8b6652c5/

Comment: According to the lastest post on the forum that GordonB linked to, `X-UA-Compatible` does work on Intranet sites, but only when it's issued as an HTTP header, not as a meta tag.

Comment: TRiG : Tried setting it in IIS already.  Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) will help you.

```cs
if (window.navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
    // This is an IE browser. What mode is the engine in?
    if (document.documentMode==8) // IE8
    {
        alert('IE8')
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Not IE8 or in Compatibilty mode');
    }
}
```

according to false status (not IE8 or in Compatibilty mode) you can redirect the user to a page that says how to set his/her browser.
I wonder to know if there is an automatic script to do this?