# IE Compatibility mode issue on Intranet pages (only internal, works fine externally)

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, intranet, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a strange, and frustrating problem that unfortunately I can't even demonstrate for reasons that will become clear...

I am using a 3rd party component as a HTML editor / file uploader on my Intranet:
http://www.dmxzone.com/go?18424

For some reason, it wasn't working correctly and then I noticed that IE was switching to compatibility mode automatically when it viewed a page with this component on it. If I hit F12 and switch back to IE9 or IE8 mode, it works fine. It also works in Firefox and Chrome etc.
I contacted the developers who were very helpful, but it turns-out if I make the script available externally on the Internet, it works. This problem only occurs if viewed internally, on our network, so I guess it's not their fault.

If I view the web page on the web server itself using http://Localhost/page.asp it works whereas if I use http://theservername/page.asp it does the compatibility mode switch and fails.

A little research suggested using the following meta tag would prevent this behaviour:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

but that doesn't work. Neither does disabling the 'automatically recover from page layout errors with compatibility view' option in IE (which we could do at a push, as this is only an Intranet application.)

I've tried using Fiddler to see if the page or headers are any different when viewed on internally but I can't spot anything. The Intranet zone is 'trusted'.

We use a proxy (Webroot) for our web-filtering, which I'm suspicious of but that could be a red herring.

If anybody has some suggestions (other than don't use IE :p ) then I would be very grateful

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot more research, I found out that:

> X-UA-Compatible does work on Intranet sites, but only when it's issued
>   as an HTTP header, not as a meta tag

[thanks stackoverflow!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047154/forcing-intranet-users-to-view-webpage-in-ie8-mode-not-compatibility-mode)

So with a bit more reading and experimentation, I found that adding:

```
<% Response.AddHeader "X-UA-Compatible", "IE=Edge"  %>
```

at the top of the page, fixes the problem.