# How do I get IE9 to recognise a web page as IE9 standards?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I have this web page that begins with `<!-- DOCTYPE html -->`, which I believe would suffice to indicate HTML 5 and make IE9 interpret it as "IE9 standards". However, when I navigate to it, IE9 shows it as "Browser mode: IE9 Compat View", "Document mode: IE7 standards".

The two first lines in the page are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

As a result, some of the layout is rendered incorrectly. For example, a right-aligned table cell shows left-aligned. If I manually set IE to "Browser mode: IE9", "Document mode: IE9 standards", then things look perfect. Other browsers work fine.

What do I need to change in order to make IE9 recognise HTML 5 and prevent it from working in compatibility mode? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried it without the `xmlns`?

Comment: are you running over an intranet? if so check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742853/force-internet-explorer-8-browser-mode-in-intranet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things I do:

```
<!doctype html>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

And take out the XMLNS

Using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This has fixed "Document mode", which now appears as IE9, but "Browser mode" is still "IE9 Compat View". Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @CesarGon I don't think Its of importance for the Users. See here:
http://superuser.com/questions/321403/how-to-change-browser-mode-in-ie9-permanently

I haven't tested all this myself so maybe walk over to another computer and try it where you haven't enabled developer mode.

Comment: For people not wanting to click: I don't think you can really affect the browser mode setting; this seems to be a developer debugging feature. If a user is running IE9, the browser mode will be IE9 or IE9 Compatibility View. You can affect the compatibility view setting by using the X-UA-Compatible <meta> tag or HTTP header (though, watch out for the Tools -> Compatibility View settings - > "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting).