# onhashchange and backstack only working on localhost

Tags: asp.net, web-config, localhost

I am using hash change and onhashchange event in my webpage. When testing locally (w/ asp.net development server), `window.onhashchange` event fires properly and hash changes are pushed into backstack. However when the website is deployed to a server (IIS 7.5), visiting from the SAME browser on the SAME client machine, the event doesn't fire and though I can see the hash changed in the address bar, they aren't pushed into backstack and back key leads to previous page. Is there any IIS/asp.net config I should tweak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be IE Compatibility mode. The problem was solved by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5887271/986080.