# how do I properly show on IE8, with compatibility mode enabled, a web application which does not support compatibility mode?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Let me start saying that thought I know there are two or three good answers about this on stackoverflow, none (or any other I found on the internet) works for me.

My application doesn't support internet explorer compatibility mode, and my client workstations are set with the "Display all intranet sites in compatibilty view option" check box checked.

I tried various solution, among which:
- using meta tags such as  `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge>`
with all variants of IE versions. I tried putting this as the first element after  tag and right after  tag. 
- I also tried putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` to force HTML5 doctype, which is the current preferred solution suggested by Microsoft to force the browser to work with the highest engine available (since it is HTML5 doctype).

Internet explorer 8 couldn't care less about all of these, and keeps happily running in compatibility mode ("IE8 Compat View" says the debugger).

on the other hand, using `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge>` works fine for IE9, forcing compatibility mode off.

My question is if anybody knows how to force once and forever IE8 compatibility mode off from webpage, or even server side (Weblogic 12c), programmatically.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks chaenu, this is very similar indeed, problem is that none of the proposed solution works for me, I have already gone through it. I basically tried all possible values for `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="...` with no luck on IE8, it looks like the browser is ignoring the meta tag. I don't think I am getting this meta tag wrong since it is fixing the problem for IE9.

Comment: Yes, I think you did everything right, it's the IE8 that doesn't let you override the settings.

Comment: You should have cited the questions you had checked and explained how your question differs. It seems that it really doesn’t, i.e. this is a duplicate.

Comment: The answer marked as correct to the duplicate question doesn't appear correct to me and others. How should I behave in this case?

Comment: You cannot "force" IE to display a specific document mode from within a webpage.  You can only request a mode and hope that some other setting does not override the request.  Possible overrides include group policies forcing a site (or page) into a specific mode, user choice (placing a site into a zone or the compatibility view settings), and so on.  It is better to code accordingly.  Use runtime detection (perhaps the `documentMode` and `compatMode` properties) to see if the current values match your expectations.  If not, display a warning to the user and redirect them to a help page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the "old" rendering, and no button to show up on the toolbar so that users can switch modes you can use this:

```
<head>
  <!-- Mimic Internet Explorer 8 -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
  <title>My Web Page</title>
</head>
```

other options (old and new) include:IE=5, IE=7, IE=8, or IE=edge

(edge equals highest mode available)

Comment: attempted this as well, still no luck. page source code shows: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` but IE 8 is sitll running in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already posted in [Force "Internet Explorer 8" browser mode in intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742853/force-internet-explorer-8-browser-mode-in-intranet/4130343#4130343), but not accepted as correct answer.

> If your intranet uses default settings for IE, IE7 Standards Mode is enforced for intranet sites regardless of any website settings.

From [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx):

> Compatibility View and the Enterprise
>
> A large number of line-of-business websites are Internet Explorer 7 capable today. In order to preserve compatibility, Internet Explorer 8 ships with smart defaults based on zone evaluation. In the default state, all sites on the public internet display in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode (Compatibility View off) and all intranet websites display in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode (Compatibility View on).
>
> Let’s look at some examples. If you navigate to sites on your local intranet like `http://myPortal` and `http://sharepoint/sites/mySite`, Internet Explorer 8 identifies itself with a User Agent string of ‘7’, Version Vector of ‘7’, and displays webpages that trigger standards mode in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode. This combination allows webpages that worked correctly in Internet Explorer 7 to continue to do so in IE8.

The only way to solve your problem is to uncheck the option on your client's workstations.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I decided to only provide the link, as I didn't want to duplicate an answer from another stack overflow question. Would it be a better solution to mark this question as duplicate?

Comment: the answer "The only way to solve your problem is to uncheck the option on your client's workstations" is hardly the correct answer, since there are tens of posts claiming they solved it via the meta tags, though it is not working for me. I'm still trying and the behavior is now looking very inconsistent to me. It is working properly with HTML doctype and if I point to my local environment ("localhost" which is considered "local intranet" by IE8, as per lower status bar) and NOT if I point to the client's server, which, given I am in a VPN, are still considered "local intranet".