# Why does my website render in IE8 compatibility mode?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, view, compatibility, ie8-compatibility-mode

We are using a js library that is not yet compatible with IE9. In order for our website to render correctly, we have add the following meta tag until the library is updated:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

The doctype is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
```

This works as expected in IE9 (Browser Mode is IE8 Compatibility Mode).

In IE8 on localhost it is also correct (Browser Mode is IE8), but when viewing the test site on our server, the Browser Mode is IE8 Compatibility View.

What have I missed?

Comment: I the server sending a UA-Compatible header as well? If not, is the type served correct?

Answer (score 5):

This applies only if your server is on your intranet :

There is an option in the Compatibility View Settings that force IE to use the compatibility mode for intranet websites :

Tools menu, then Compatibility View Settings and uncheck 'Display intranet sites in compatibility mode'

I hope it helps you.

Comment: There is an other question about this with better answers than mine :) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8