# Override Internet Explorer intranet compability mode using JSF

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, jsf-2, cross-browser

Microsoft Internet Explorer switches to compability mode for intranet pages. I found a solution for the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8/5887546#5887546), but it applies to an ASP.net web application only. I however develop a JSF application and would like to implement the same workaround.

Is there an expert who knows where to put the according directives and how to reformulate the ASP.net settings directives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily implement a servlet filter to add that header, see [here](http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/11/adding-headers-to-requests-in-filters.html) for a tutorial or [here](http://flavio.tordini.org/http-headers-filter) for some ready-to-use code.

Comment: Late but still: Your answer has helped me solve my problem back then.

Answer (score 0):

This is far more clearly explained and solved here:
http://joensen.eu/2011/11/27/change-ie-compatibility-in-jsf/
(easy implementation of a Filter)