# HTML5 doctype commented out for IE10 PP2 but not Chrome

Tags: html, iis, iis-7.5

I have a simple HTML5 page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
Test
</html>
```

On my local IIS, IE 10 PP2 and Chrome return this page fine. The doctype is in the header.

But when I serve this page up from our IIS 7.5 on a remote server, Chrome works but IE 10 PP2 has the doctype commented out in the response.

```
<!-- DOCTYPE html -->
```

Is my server missing an update that would cause this to happen?

(I made simple test pages with VS 2012 with real HTML 5 features like the "placeholder" attribute that work locally in both IE 10 and Chrome, bot only in Chrome from our server.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Perhaps that's because your so-called HTML5 page is not HTML5-compliant. An `html` element always contains a `head` element, followed by a `body` element. `#PCDATA` (text) is not allowed, as far as I know.

Comment: @Tinctorius that shouldn't really matter, browsers are very forgiving when it comes to markup (for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641997/is-it-necessary-to-write-head-body-and-html-tags)

Comment: Possibly true.  I was trying to simplify my issue. My real issue is I have an ASP.NET 4.5 app that has HTML 5 features that work locally in both IE 10 and Chrome, but when on remote server only in Chrome. When looking at the response, the DOCTYPE is commented out in IE 10.

Comment: Very strange ... not sure why a server would affect a doctype though, maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015162/force-iis-to-allow-transitional-doctype (if not I'm out of ideas)

Comment: When run with a Intranet address or locally I've found IE often to behave more "loosely". Perhaps try running locally but with an entry in your hosts file to fake a domain name to see what affect it has, to add to the debugging.

Comment: @Sean Dunwoody our IIS 7.5 server is on our local network (same domain). This will be an intranet application.

Comment: In that case, the answer in Sean Dunwoody's last link contains a links to the answer.

Comment: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg

Comment: I just noticed when I press F12 in IE, that Browser Mode was set to IE10 Compat View.  When I changed it to Browser Mode: IE10 it stopped commenting my DOCTYPE. But it changes back to Compat Mode when I reopen IE. :(

Comment: Adding what Sean suggested in his link to my web.config did in fact fix the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my web.config stopped IE from rendering in compatibility mode on my local intranet.

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```