# Printing issue in IE8 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp, printing, sandbox

I created a JSP page in which I created a icon to print using...

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">
    <img src="images/printIcon.gif" alt="Print the Records" 
          width="40" height="40" border="0" /> 
</a>
```

The page works fine in my local machine in all browsers. But when I load in sandbox, it works only in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE8 it skips the content of `body` in the first two pages and prints the next pages.

Is there a problem with IE8 or am I missing any settings?

Comment: that is a different environment

Comment: Could be your other code, specifically your CSS. Can you show us more?

Comment: actually I can't put the whole code it is 150 LOC, the main problem is  it works in my local machine even in IE8 that's what bugging me.

Comment: If it works in the real thing, simply accept the fact that the simulated environment is flawed.  They usually are.

Comment: Well we went live with the same code, it is not working there either

Comment: You said, _"... it works in my local machine even in IE8..."_  If that's true then your local machine would not care if the file was served locally or live.  All JS runs _client-side_ no matter where the file is stored.  This is making no sense now.

Comment: ok it has nothing to do with javascript and you have ruled out CSS, can you at least tell me where to look at. We have 2 testing environments sandbox and qual. It works only if we point through local.

Comment: There does not seem to be anything wrong with the JavaScript you posted above, and you've posted nothing else of relevant substance.  Perhaps you can post a link to the online demo.  [Read this](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) for some clues about why you're not getting much help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the Compatibility view of the IE. This fixed the problem

[Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a "Low" directory in your temp directory usually located here.
C:\Users(username)\appdata\Local\Temp\Low

reference : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_xp/ie8-printing-does-not-work-preview-empty/920588e5-ccc4-4e24-83d6-606d5e3b1c70

Cheers!