# IE9 always reverting to IE7 standards on my DEV server, not in PROD

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I have a HTML5 site that when viewed in IE9 on my DEV server it always defaults to IE7 standards and looks broken.  Using Developer Tools, I can manually switch the Document mode to IE9 Standards (Page Default), then the page looks good.  However, the same page in PROD shows that it defaults to IE9 Standards.

Is it true that whenever the IE browser displays the "Compatibility Icon", does that mean there are CSS or HTML issues?  Because the icon only shows up on the PROD version of the website.

I would add the tag x-ua-compatible tag, but it must not be best practices because it doesn't validate by the W3C.  Is adding the tag the ONLY way to fix?

Comment: IIRC we ran into an issue of intranet vs. internet sites .. (also, interesting, wrt ["X-" headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561381/custom-http-headers-naming-conventions))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8) - also valid for IE9.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We ended up adding a dynamic check to set the meta tag if we were in the DEV environment and leave the PROD boxes alone, it seems to be working fine.  Thanks Lucero and pst for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox on the Compatibility mode settings that say something like "Use Compatibility modefor intranet sites". Try setting it off on the clients's IEs.