# IE forced to compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a popup with over 1500 checkboxes, after checking the checkboxes when the user closes the popup the list of checked checkboxes are populated on the main page. This functionality is working fine. The problem occurs when the user selects a lot of checkboxes say over 600-700 checkboxes, in this case a huge amount of HTML is injected into the DOM. This forces IE to compatibility mode. Has anyone faced such a situation? How can i solve it? removing this functionality or reducing the number of checkboxes is not an option.

Very simple code to inject HTML:

```
$("#" + DestDiv).html(listString);
```

And the generated HTML is perfect, I crosschecked it.

Comment: Code please... And do you use the correct `<!DOCTYPE .. >`?

Comment: I am using liferay so no DOCTYPE is needed for individual portlet.

Comment: Try to add one and check, for now, is it generating a `<!DOCTYPE .. >` or not?

Comment: yes boss... DOCTYPE did the trick....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make **Internet Explorer** not go to the Compatibility mode, please use a `<!DOCTYPE ...>`

Good to use this doctype, if you are not sure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1500 checkboxes ?!? What the ...

- A long answer about Doctype declaration on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7685060/488861)

I haven't heard about a size limit forcing compatibility mode.
Don't you think it's because you test one time on a server and one time locally ?

Cheers