# weird wamp bug table has no border on IE

Tags: html, css, django, internet-explorer, wamp

I'm working on a django project and I recently deployed it. It's on a closed company network so I can't show it to you.

What I have is a table that presents data. I used css to do a border collapse and then added a solid border to the tr so there's a seperating line between each row.

Now this works fine when i'm using the development server, but when deploying with wamp, there's no border between the rows. This happens only on IE (we have IE8), and only when using the wamp server. On the same computer, the same IE and the same code - everything works fine for the development server

Now I'll just add that I did have to use  at some point for the IE, but it still is  standrads mode on the wamp, I checked.

I'm using wamp 5.1.7 with Django 1.4, mod_wsgi33 on a 32bit windows xp with Python2.6

Any help would be much appreciated as this bug is driving me hairless

Comment: Sounds suspect that the same code in the same browser/os would behave differently. Is the Doctype also the same? Press F12 (developer tools) in IE and see if the "working" browser version matches. Maybe there are some JavaScript doing something? Or you could also try adding the border on the TD instead of TR tag.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! I solved it just now.Using F12 it turns out it was using the IE7 standards mode instead of the 8 so I added a little meta beneath the doctype to force it to the IE8 standards and that solved it. Not sure how the wamp did that though

Answer (score 0):

IE will defaults to "Compatibility Mode" for sites it deems "Intranet". My guess is it considered localhost to be "Intranet" so it switched to IE7 mode. You can read more about this here: [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

In short, it can be fixed on a per computer basis by changing the Compatibility mode settings (or removing your site from the "Intranet" list), or it can be fixed by adding the right headers to your code: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`