# PrimeFaces RowEditor - No Icon displayed

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, icons

I'm having trouble using the p:rowEditor from PrimeFaces.
The problem is, the icon to click on is not displayed.

I did not modify the style class and use the default icon.
Everything works fine in FF, Chrome and IE9.

Unfortunately, my project is supposed to run on IE8... but the icon is not visible there.
Since this is the default browser we use at my workplace, there is no possibility to switch to another browser.

Do you guys know any work-around or fix, in order to make the rowEditor at least clickable? A text saying "Edit" is fine, instead of the icon.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you try to insert that: `.ui-icon{ background-color:white;}`

Comment: Ich tried that, but it does not do anything :-( It seems like, the rowEditor does not know which styleclass to use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is "set the `X-UA-Compatible` header(Primefaces version >= 3.0, if lower version you just add `meta` tag to `h:head`)":

```
<h:head>
  <f:facet name="first"> // remove this tag if primefaces's version is lower than 3.0
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="EmulateIE8" />
  </f:facet>
  // other contents
</h:head>
```

**Read more:** [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much! Now the default page standard is set to IE8 and it works fine!

Comment: Does not work on my end (Primefaces 3.5, IE8). Also, `EmulateIE8` is not a valid value, but `IE=EmulateIE8` is (see the MSDN page linked in the answer). I would edit the answer, but I'm not comfortable with that as it is accepted and seems to have actually solved the OP's problem.

Comment: @zb226 Post new answer, i used PF 3.1 3.2 when i post this answer :-)

Comment: @RongNguyen: I consider this question closed, so it's fine the way it is :) But for posterity: The problem on my end was the intranet-detection of IE8 and the fallback to IE7-compatibility, I needed to set the `X-UA-Compatible` header on the server side, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8