# IE 9 to IE 11 will not display box-shadow

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Good ol' Internet Explorer will not display the box shadow I've given it. It displays fine in every other browser. I figured at first, maybe it was a separate container issue, but that wasn't it. I added another div with the shadow atop and it still didn't display? I am not sure as to why. Fiddle attached is what I am trying to replicated.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GYf29/

```
   body {
        background:gray;
    }
    .contain {
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/The_sun1.jpg) -175px -175px;
        border:5px solid white;
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #444;
    }

<div class="contain"></div>
```

Comment: If it works in the fiddle but not in your page, is the page rendering in a "Standards" [document mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699340.aspx)?

Comment: Negative. IE ll is rendering is normal mode.

Comment: Well, they may not all say "Standards." But, you don't want "Quirks" or "Compatibility."

Comment: Seems "Compatibility" was applied to local intranet/host, but not globally. Odd. Gone ahead and disabled it entirely. Thanks.

Comment: IE will [default to compatibility mode for intranet URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8) due to an assumption that such sites are less likely to be ready for "Standards" mode. Though, a site can be explicit about browser and document mode with an `X-UA-Compatible` header.

Comment: Never knew that. Good to know. Thanks again.