# Glimpse not running on remote IIS server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, entity-framework-5, glimpse

Used Nuget and installed Glimpse: Core 1.8.1.0, ADO 1.7, ASP.NET 1.6, EF5 1.6.0.0, and Mvc4 1.5.2 extensions.

Glimpse works great when I launch the web application locally using the VS IIS Express (remote DB). However, I don't get the Glimpse icon when "publishing" the MVC application to our remote IIS server.

Here's what I've tried and noticed:

•ignoring the LocalPolicy in my web.config:

```
<glimpse defaultRuntimePolicy="On" endpointBaseUri="~/Glimpse.axd" >
<logging level="Trace" />    
<runtimePolicies>
  <ignoredTypes>
    <add type="Glimpse.AspNet.Policy.LocalPolicy, Glimpse.AspNet"/>
  </ignoredTypes>
</runtimePolicies>
</glimpse>
```

•  Running Glimpse.axd and press [Turn On Glimpse] shows an hour glass for several  seconds  and trace the DEBUG and INFO startup logs to file.

•  Turning on the Glimpse log does shows DEBUG's for a new default MVC route request and 1 info.

```
2014-01-22 15:26:15.2282 | INFO | Replaced IView of type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView', named 'Index', with proxy implementation. | 
2014-01-22 15:26:17.6600 | DEBUG | RuntimePolicy set to 'Off' by IRuntimePolicy of type 'Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy' during RuntimeEvent 'EndRequest'.
```

• Below appears at the end of the page source as expected.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&amp;hash=e5937894'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_metadata&amp;hash=e5937894&amp;callback=glimpse.data.initMetadata'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_request&amp;requestId=3d258479-bc96-4b0c-a469-d6b713fdb0fc&amp;hash=e5937894&amp;callback=glimpse.data.initData'></script>
```

(F12) console shows the following errors:

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&hash=e5937894, line 3652 character 29
SCRIPT5009: 'glimpse' is undefined Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_metadata&hash=e5937894&callback=glimpse.data.initMetadata, line 1 character 1
SCRIPT5009: 'glimpse' is undefined Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_request&requestId=923b9a70-39ac-4639-b812-833e1d051c08&hash=e5937894&callback=glimpse.data.initData, line 1 character 1
```

Comment: Is seems that Glimpse is effectively running as you mention the script tags being rendered at the bottom of the page. Do you see Javascript errors when looking at the console from withing the developer tools (F12)?

Answer (score 0):

Problem and Answer was glaring right at me from :

```
HTML1202: http://mysite/ is running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View' is checked. 
mysite:1111
```

Disabled via: [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Now all is working and after years of Asp.forms client side neglect I'm returning to client side debugging via (F12).  thanks to cgijbels