# Add <!Doctype> in a react component

Tags: reactjs

am trying without success to add a <!Doctype html> tag at the begging of my rendered component. Am doing a email signature generator where the user copies the rendered table but can't find a way to include the tag. Is that even possible? Thank you

```
  function renderHTML() {
    return employeData
      .filter((nom) => nom.value === nomValue)
      .map((employe) => {
        return (
          <html key={employe._id} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
              <span
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: `<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--<![endif]-->
`,
                }}
              />
              <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />
              <meta
                httpEquiv="Content-Type"
                content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
              />
              <meta
                name="viewport"
                content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
              />

              <span
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                  __html: `<!--[if mso]>
      <xml>
```

Comment: React renders the App content into _predefined_ HTML (index.html), normally within `<div id="root">`, you're supposed to edit that one.

Comment: The thing is I have a copyblock inside a page with the rendered table, the only thing I can't insert is this tag

Comment: Note that you cannot have a `span` element inside a `head` element and have valid HTML. Just use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on the `head` element itself, if you must.

Comment: You might want to check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523487/set-doctype-using-javascript

Comment: Thank you I will look into it