# IE8 html5shiv...not all styles are being applied

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, html5shiv

I've been struggling for days to get my site to look right on IE8 (because stupid banks haven't updated their browsers), and I've narrowed it down a bit.

I'm using HTML5 tags (not supported by IE8) because I just can't stand unnecessary div soup. I'm using the famous HTML5shiv to get HTML elements like `section` and `article` to work in IE8. It seems that IE8 is still not reliable when it comes to these tagnames though.

Here is an example:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>ie8</title>
  <script id="html5shiv_script">/*blah blah*/</script>
  <style>
    section{display:block;}
    article{display:block;background:green;}
    article.first + article{font-size:72px;}
    article.first{color:yellow;}
    article:first-child{background:blue;}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <section>
   <article class="first">One</article>
   <article>Two</article>
   <article>Three</article>
   <article>Four</article>
   <article>Five</article>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Link: http://www.webnotes.xyz/ie8.html

I couldn't find anything about why these two styles are not being applied in IE8:

```
article.first + article{font-size:72px;}
article:first-child{background:blue;}
```

I can't deduce anything from this because IE8 is supposed to support these selectors, and in my personal website, I'm switched these selectors with classes and it still would not work.

I couldn't find anything about this by googling. Can anyone explain why these styles are being ignored in IE8?

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** I just realized this doesn't work in IE9 either.

Comment: It's not really *unnecessary* if it's the only thing the browser supports... anyway, have you tried giving them all a class of `article` and styling that?

Comment: Is this an intranet site?

Comment: @TylerH yes, this is the first thing I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @zgood it is a sponsored webpage made for companies such as banks who can only review the site internally on IE8.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you've tried since you only gave example code. For instance, I hope your real code doesn't use `script id=""` instead of `script src=""`.

Comment: @TylerH I just copied and pasted the code into the script tag. You can see if you go to the link I posted http://www.webnotes.xyz/ie8.html

Comment: Funnily enough that link is blocked by my work filter for security purposes :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem similar to this working on an intranet site of an insurance company. By default, IE will force intranet site into compatibility mode, thus breaking your selectors.

> IE makes assumption about displaying intranet sites
>   (http://someInternalSite/ vs. http://someInternalSite.myCompany.org).
>   That assumption is that intranet sites work best in compatibility
>   mode.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269781/why-compatibility-mode-for-intranet-sites)

If this is the case then maybe [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8) can help.

Also, I believe network admins can create a group policy to force IE into compatibility mode. [Reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985351.aspx)

Comment: Thanks...Good to know, but I don't think this is it. I can see that it is not in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why the example I posted wasn't working. It's because I forgot to include a doctype. `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top makes everything work. I still don't know why the actual site I'm working on doesn't work though because that has `<!DOCTYPE html>`...back to the drawing board!