# @font-face on Internet Explorer 9 on Xbox 360?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, xbox360, xbox

I'm trying to load fonts on IE9 on Xbox 360. It works perfectly fine on a regular Windows 7/Internet Explorer 9 box, but not on Xbox. Anyone knows what's the trick to get a font loading?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  src: url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.eot") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.otf") format("opentype"), url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.svg#Gotham") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; 
}

body {
  font-family: "Gotham";
}
```

**– update –**

I tried removing all font formats except woff and ttf:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Gotham";
  src: url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }
```

but IE9 still shows me times new roman as font.

Comment: where are you hosting the web server? within the xbox or in another system?

Comment: Tried various things already. Internet web server (nginx), S3, local web server (gulp), all HTTP only. The font is properly served (application/font-woff). Works in IE9, 10, Chrome, Safari ... just not on the Xbox.

Comment: sorry i dont have an xbox right now, so I am pretty much trying to visualize the issue. is the documents mode set to edge? Since I am assuming that you are testing on Intranet, IE jumps to compatibility view, hence it goes into ie6 standards which has no font-face support

Comment: please tell me if this helps::: go to settings in IE -> Compatibility view settings -> uncheck the option "Display intranet sites in Compatibility view" . That is if you are testing an intranet site

Comment: Yes, meta tags are set to IE9 and edge. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`. Since it's the same when hosted on a web server, I don't think the compatibility mode jumps in.

Comment: go to the compatibility settings of IE and uncheck the box. Just because you specify a meta tag in your page, IE does not listen to it. The meta tag applies only for outside domains. Intranet domains are not covered in the meta tag. I had similar issue which was handled by unchecking the box in settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369132/ie-conditional-statement-displaying-div-even-though-the-condition-says-it-should  refer this link to the answer of my question by the user "adrianba"

Comment: The problem is not Internet Explorer 9 itself, it's IE9 on Xbox and there's no Compatibility Mode nor anything. I'm running it on my company web server, it's not Intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link [here](http://www.broken-links.com/2012/10/16/internet-explorer-on-xbox-360/) and the official documentation found in [MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn532261(v=vs.85).aspx#fonts). it says that .eot files are not supported. So my suggestion is to use the ".woff" or ".ttf" file types for font using @font-face.

Hope this helps. **Happy coding :)**

Comment: I have the .woff and .ttf files in the definition. If .eot doesn't work, it should automatically fallback to .otf, .woff etc. no?

Comment: try re-ordering the font types and check if the location is correct as well. Any errors in developer console?

Comment: also where is the site/ page hosted from?

Comment: It's on S3. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No luck with this. See update above in the question.