# Why is my Bootstrap/IE9 browsing experience different when using localhost versus the computer name?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

On my development machine (Win 7 IIS7.5) using IE9, If I browse my bootstrap 3 site using localhost/appname it behaves as expected.  If I browse the same app using computer-name/appname its as if I am browsing from a phone (the menu gets tucked under the button to slide out the menu, and the layout generally looks busted, the slide out is mangled too).  I know the starting point for bootstrap 3 is mobile first.  It looks like the responsive bits to get me back to desktop are not happening when using the computer name in the url.

I did a view source on the IE9 browsing alternatives(localhost|computer-name) and saved them to disk and ran them through a diff tool. No html differences at all.  Its the same IE9 browser, the same windows 7 box iis7.5, the same app, the same rendered html, just different url entry.  What is really to blame?

This same app works with either localhost or computer-name using firefox, chrome, and safari.

When I post the site to our test server using an alias in the url IE9 is busted there too.  This is why I need to figure this out versus being content to just use localhost.

We are behind a proxy server.  I can browse external sites that use bootstrap 3 with my IE9 and they look fine.

I've also browsed my dev box with Fiddler open but not seeing anything obvious though it may be there and I just don't know.

Comment: have you looked in your console? are there any errors?

Comment: There are no errors.  Why the -1 whoever?

Comment: no errors in the ie9 developer console? it's just difficult to believe that the same source can act differently and there is no clue as to why. I have a feeling something isn't being loaded properly. have you tried a different version of IE? Have you checked the components on the bootstrap site to make sure they're compatible with IE9?

Comment: There were no errors in the IE9 console.  There was a log about running in Compatibility View because 'Display intranet sites in Compatiblity View' is checked. This was the issue.

Comment: consider adding that as an answer and accepting it for others benefit :) glad you have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was compatability mode had been decided for me for intranet sites.  I overrode the behaviour in my web.config file per the solution found at [Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

Thank you @pennstatephil for mentioning the ie9 console for clues.