# Styles stopped working after moving the code to a network drive

Tags: html, css

I have created a site that works fine on my pc when running it in VS 10.
However, when I moved source files to a network drive, styles stopped working for IE???

What can be wrong?

P.S. I do not copy a source code here because it is working fine

Comment: First guess, an absolute reference to a css file.

Comment: Chrome and FF work fine, otherwise they would have the same problem

Comment: If it is just on IE, but other browsers work fine, try cleaning up cache

Comment: Tip: IE, on latest versions, has a debugging console feature (F12). Open the Network interface (Ctrl + 4) and enable traffic capture... You will see if there was some file missing

Comment: My guess is that you are using a different version of IE

Answer (score 0):

I have solved half of the problem by putting the following into my .css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3fY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot);
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3fY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot);
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXZ2MAKAc2x4R1uOSeegc5U.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTXhCUOGz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
}
```

and removing

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

from my .htm file

Styles now are displayed in all browsers, however, `Open Sans` with `font-weight:400` does not work in IE, it only shows `Open Sans` with `font-weight:300`

Comment: font-weight does not work good cross-browser, it is a well known issue. http://css-tricks.com/watch-your-font-weight/

Answer (score 0):

If it works locally but not on your intranet, it could be potentially be intranet compatability mode setting interferring.  Check the IE developer console window to see if there is a log about running in Compatibility View which happens when your IE browser has 'Display intranet sites in Compatability View' checked.  Had a simliar IE only problem and fixed it with [override compatibility mode in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

Comment: Changing css to have a link to fonts location solved the problem, but still I do not think it is a good idea to use the link since it can change sometimes in the future and styles will break again. What do you think?