# Override IE Local Intranet Settings

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

The website that I am developing is added to the list of local intranet sites in IE browsers.

[image]

Then in compatibility view settings the check box for the "display intranet sites in Compatibility View" is checked.

[image]

Problem, the site that I am developing right now is displayed as compatibility view in IE browsers (For very obvious reason).

What I need to do, is to find a way not to display the site in compatibility view.

What I tried so far is adding the below header but to no avail.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

and

```html
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Removing the said IE browser settings is not an option since there are 300,000 computers to modify around the world (Lucky for me).

Question, Is there a way we can override this settings so that my site will not render in compatibility mode?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue..... I am using a published web site on my localhost (http://localhost/expression.local ) where I have added localhost to the Intranet security zone.....are you testing from a VS proxy? localhost:port ? you may need to publish the site for testing purposes.
File>Properties to determine which IE security zone a page maps to
f12>Emulation tab to determine how the emulation mode is established.
go to https://www.modern.ie/en-us/f12?url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fexpression.local%2f&mode=Edge for more detailed instructions.

Comment: Try adding *.google.com in the intranet security zone, you can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another thread which has a similar solution to your second one as the answer, but with a little bit extra

> For IIS, just add the below code to the web.config. Worked for me with
>   IE9.
>
> ```
> <system.webServer>
>   <httpProtocol>
>     <customHeaders>
>       <clear />
>       <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
>     </customHeaders>
>   </httpProtocol>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

[Override intranet compatibility mode IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

Use this tag, and it will disable the compatibility view in most of the IE Versions:
    `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />`