# Why X-UA-Compatible mode is working in UAT and Not in Production

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

We set X-UA-Compatible mode in our jsp/html tags but still is not working in production environment but works fine in UAT. Basically in UAT URL IE11 in Developer tool the document mode was set to 10 but in Prod it is setting as 5.
Can you please let me know what are possibilities or configuration I can check, why it is setting up different.

Thanks
ananda

Comment: One thing worth checking is whether the setting is being overridden by the HTTP headers, since the prod server may be configured differently.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8/13305862#13305862

Comment: thanks for quick replay, can you please explain more, what server your talking about your. I have checked/compared apache and tomcat configuration file.

Comment: also I observed that the User agent in IE is different for uat and prod using same IE 11 browser.