# Angular ng-disabled is not working in IE browser

Tags: angularjs

I don't know why ng-disabled is not working in IE but it is wotking in chrome,firefox. Here i am checking condition if data is 0 i making button disabled.

HTML Code:

```
<span ng-if="appDetails.buildsummary.buildcount<=0"><button class="disabled" disabled>0 builds</button></span>
```

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  You might want to consider dropping support for IE 10, since very few users would likely still be using this outdated browser.

Comment: But in the above Html Code you haven't used ng-disabled ?

Comment: we don't know what version  the end user using i need to fix this using code not setttings. please help me with code.

Comment: disabled is enough as what i refereed as per document.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Internet Explorer is set to display intranet sites in compability mode. It can give all sorts of weird behaviour.
Hit the ALT-key and find it under Tools.

Comment: i want to fix this bug using angularjs code not with settings. We dont the version what end user is using so i should be fix using code.Thank you

Comment: See this on how to override IE compability mode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518256/override-intranet-compatibility-mode-ie8