# Why doesn't my page display correctly in Internet Explorer?

Tags: php, html, css, validation

**Edit: There is a somewhat strange solution to this question. Check my answer posted below**

I am working on [this site](http://vestervang-dejret.dk) and it works perfectly... Or at least, it *did* work perfectly until earlier today.

I don't know what I did, I made some minor changes to the code but **no changes to the front page.** The site is tested to work correctly in FF and Chrome but of course it crashes in Internet Explorer.

I have tried a lot of standard "troubleshooting techniques" like taking parts of the code and making it comments but nothing seems to be working.

**It should look like:**

- The "content holder" should be surrounded by two green boxes and should be centered (Chrome and FF works)
- When you hover the tabs drop downs should appear (again, works in Chrome and FF)
- Just noticed the font actually changes in IE

My deadline is 18. September (this Saturday), so I would love quick answers.

I think the problem might have something to do with my [stylesheet](http://vestervang-dejret.dk/vestervang.css) since that is the only thing affecting the front page that I could've changed without *thinking about it.*

### Oh, and just to mention...

A part of the site is build in PHP (which is why you can't see it) but it is mostly just "require/include", that I use.

Comment: There is a lot of noise in your question, makes me not want to answer it.

Comment: What is the difference between what you are seeing and what you are expecting to see?  I'm able to see the page in IE7.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way - how can I improve my question? You are welcome to edit it, if you'd like

Comment: You should really go into more detail about what doesn't work as expected in what versions of IE.

Comment: @recursive Update is coming up!

Comment: @Latze: copy your changes to a dev box, revert the production box, and do you work on the development box......

Comment: Pekka, updated. Hope it helps. Please stop downvoting, I know these questions are pain in the ass but you guys are always so helpful ;)

Comment: something not working as expected and something crashing an app are two very different problems and makes it hard to make a good diagnosis. it may benefit you to be concise about what the problem is and try to leave out details about deadlines and complaints. I would say that's why you are getting down votes

Comment: Voted to close as not a real question, if the question's edited to add useful information as suggested by @Pekka and others, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: Come on people, there was no reason to close this. It may be a poor question but it was answerable as you all can see.

Comment: @ChaosPandion ff it's been correctly answered, then I guess I was wrong. Voted to re-open.

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks for all the response. Try checking out my new update, it might explain why my site was not displayed correctly and why it suddently just happened

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing the comments before the DOCTYPE tag.  Sometimes IE doesn't like them.  See this question for reference: [Can comments appear before the DOCTYPE declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-html-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration)

Comment: I was just going to say that IE seems to be in quirks mode, so something isn't validating properly, but it was fixed in the next refresh :) Use http://validator.w3.org to catch things that can escape the eye.

Comment: @Fanis I actually did use the w3 validator, it stated that nothing was wrong... Very weird! The reason why is suddenly worked was probably that I just fixed it ;)

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you mean by "crash". In IE6/7 the only major difference I see is the content is left-aligned and not centered. You can fix this by add `text-align: center` to the `<body>` tag, and then a `text-align: left` within your `div#container_front` to restore text alignment to normal.

On top of that, but minor-ish, the translucent block with the contact information doesn't span the full width of the background picture it's over.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found out what caused this problem. If you guys are running Windows you might have noticed some updates today and yesterday? Apparently Internet Explorer amongst other things has been updated.

This made parts of my page not display correctly. For example in the semi transparent box there was supposed to be two links (one where it says "klik for mere info" and one that says "Klik her" in grey). Both links were displayed but neither worked.

This was caused by a filter I used in order to use a semi transparent background (check out this site for more information about what was once required to use semi transparent backgrounds in IE). The filter is as follows:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=scale, src='/example.png');
```

This used to work but the new update has caused this filter to ruin the page. I also noted that IE now identifies and uses styles with `[attributes]` (found out this because when I deleted the filter, the background was still there and was still semi transparent).

Internet Explorer also no more ignores `!important` tags.

**NOTE:** All the above mentioned statements are based on speculations and minor tests. The only tests I have made to prove these statements are the ones I performed on this site in order to fix the first problem to begin with. So don't get pissed if what I just stated is all wrong :) And by the way I "use" Internet Explorer 8 so I don't know if it works in IE 6/7. I never really use IE though