# IE Rendering Problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been developing a website template for my school website. I have finished all necessary development but now have noticed a problem. When opening the site in IE, it does not align everything as it does when it is loaded in Chrome or Firefox. I'm guessing that there is some CSS property that is not being handled properly by IE (this problem is more obvious on wide-screen monitors).

I have uploaded the template here: http://test.victoriaparkci.com/tpl2/

CSS is here: http://test.victoriaparkci.com/tpl2/style.css

How would I fix this problem?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: what versions of IE are you having problems in? @zzzzBov weak comment.

Comment: All versions of IE are giving problems (though I didn't expect IE9 to do that). @zzzzBov I already web develop...just having problems on the style I used this time.

Comment: It is coming up bad in 6,7,8 and 9 according to Adobe BrowserLab.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the content above from the `DOCTYPE Element`, a page should start with doctype

this content :

```
<!--VICTORIA PARK COLLEGIATE INSTITUTE SCHOOL WEBSITE

All of this website's material and content is owned by the administration of

    Victoria Park C.I., 15 Wallingford Rd, North York, ON, Canada.

Prior permission must be obtained before use, modification or replication of this website's code or content.-->
```

Comment: The reason you should move the comment is because comments before the DOCTYPE cause IE to [render in Quirks mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-html-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration/4897850#4897850).

Comment: +1: this is the correct answer. Also +1 for @Cheran's comment which explains why it is the correct answer (this is a point that really should have been made in the answer)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! That also explains why the template was working in the earlier stages! IE really needs to start following the browser crowd...

Answer (score 0):

What I notice is that the content div is failing to expand with the length of body_right. Try floating the content DIV to the left.

```
#content {
    float:left;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #ececec;
    padding: 0 10px 30px 5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

From my experience, usually a DIV will not expand to its content length because it is not floated.