# Change in HEAD makes site not work correctly?

Tags: html, css

I've added new meta tags and a different title tag to the head of my document, which makes the IE code that redraws the black background not work.

Any idea what I have missed? I can't see anything in the new code which would be causing this to break?

Old correct working code:

```
 <!-- saved from url=(0022)http://internet.e-mail -->
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>netball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"> <!--[if IE 6]>
    <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
    <link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]>
    <link href="ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type="text/css">
    .black_overlay {position:absolute; top: expression(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? document.documentElement.scrollTop+"px" : body.scrollTop+"px");}</style><![endif]-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

None working new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Netball - notice board</title>
<meta name="description" content="netball description to go here." />
<meta name="keywords" content="net, ball, netball, womens" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"> <!--[if IE 6]>
<link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link href="ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.black_overlay {position:absolute; top: expression(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? document.documentElement.scrollTop+"px" : body.scrollTop+"px");}</style><![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the title and meta tags that you changed?

Comment: Your link tags are not closed, try closing them first and retrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your link tags are malformed.  Close them and you should be good.

Comment: Hi Stefan, I thought that was working, but it's not.

I closed off the two tags:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.4.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

Is that all that needs to be done?

Comment: also the ones within the IF IE blocks

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I've done those now too. Could it also to be to do with the comment above all of the HTML in the first example? Is that pushing IE in to quirks mode or something?

Comment: Yeah, comments before the doctype are bound to give you problems.  I've found some references to buggy behavior because of it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-html-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration