# using HTML comment tag <!--...--> before doctype

Tags: html, cross-browser, comments

can i use HTML comment tag `<!-- ... -->` before `<!doctype html>` tag?

```
<!-- some comments... -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
```

Does it lead to problem in some browser?

**UPDATE: Possible Duplicate!**
[Can comments appear before the DOCTYPE declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration)

Comment: No it doesn't lead to any problem. You can use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is fully valid to do

```html
<!-- this, -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

However, it brings all versions of IE into quirks-mode (unless it is forced into no-quirks mode — see the Gotchas section below). The simplest is to move the comment below the DOCTYPE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- this, -->
```

another way is to “upgrade” the comment into a suitable conditional comment, such as :

```html
<!--[if !IE]> this <![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Note: a conditional comment does not count as a comment, in IE's world.

Alternative syntax: To forget/remember that conditional comments are a Microsoft intrusion into the HTML standard, one could for instance do

Comment: thanks, but can you add some reference link to your answer to sure me?

Comment: Copy paste from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration