# Why put # wombat urls ß before actual HTML code?

Tags: html

Every page on the [plosone website](http://www.plosone.org/) seems to have:

```
# wombat urls
 ß
```

Before any actual HTML code begins. Why would this be? I've seen a tick being placed in the title before to check (force?) UTF8 support, but it seems weird to have this whole phrase there, and even weirder to place it outside of the HTML code...

Comment: For the record it also has ``<link>`` and ``<meta>`` tags in the body, neither of which should belong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is likely a mistake

Whether intentional or by accident, the resulting code is invalid. The code snippet you reference is likely an unintentional relic from a server-side script.

[According to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#writing), documents must consist of the following parts, in the given order:

- Optionally, a single "BOM" (U+FEFF) character.
- Any number of comments and space characters.
- A DOCTYPE.
- Any number of comments and space characters.
- The root element, in the form of an html element.
- Any number of comments and space characters.

The code snippet is not a "BOM" ([byte-order mark](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark.en.php)) character, HTML comment, nor combination of space characters; [so it is invalid](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plosone.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

It is also worth noting that while most modern browsers can cope with this invalid code snippet (by ignoring it), it would trigger some versions of Internet Explorer to render the page content in "Quirks Mode". *See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4897850/2502532) to the question "[Can comments appear before the DOCTYPE declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration)"*

Comment: It's a bit of an odd text to mistakenly put there, but if there is no other logical explanation I guess you're right. Thanks!

Comment: It is possibly related to some framework, library, or platform called "wombat". A Google search turns up a number of plausible options. This particular text looks like a [Ruby comment](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#comment), and there is a [Ruby web crawler library called wombat](https://github.com/felipecsl/wombat). This is just one plausible explanation.