# Is it bad practice to put a comment before <!DOCTYPE HTML>?

Tags: html, comments

I like to head all my files with a comment about the file, but I've heard it's bad practice to put anything before the  declaration. Is it okay to put comments before this or should I leave the top of my html files for the DOCTYPE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can comments appear before the DOCTYPE declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941100/can-comments-appear-before-the-doctype-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a comment before the Doctype will trigger quirks mode in some browsers. Since the entire purpose of the Doctype (as of HTML 5) is to avoid quirks mode, yes, this is bad practise.

[image: Screenshot of validator]

Comment: Thanks, that's a good answer. I guess I'll just keep my comments under the DOCTYPE like I have been. My OCD will have to accept it.

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated. [The page you used to test](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) no longer gives a warning. And if by "some browsers" you mean Internet Explorer, that's no longer relevant.